# Finding inverse matrix

Tags: java, matrix, processing

I want to find the inverse of the XYZ to LMS colour space matrix. After looking around I found that processing has a transpose function. But I know that the transpose of a matrix doesn't always equal the inverse. I could figure out a way of calculating the inverse manually but does processing have any built in functions for this or has anyone already figure out a way to do this and doesn't mind sharing?

```
float []lms2xyzConverter(float[] lmsVals){               

   //Normalized to D65
   float[][]xyz2lms =  {   {0.4002 , 0.7076 , -0.0808},           
                           {-0.2263 , 1.1653 , 0.0457},       
                           {0.00000 , 0.00000 , 0.9182} }; 

   float [][]lms2xyz = xyz2lms.transpose();
};
```

Comment: Are you looking out to find code to do transpose of xyz2lms ?

Comment: Im looking for the inverse of xyz2lms. But if the transpose equals the inverse then yes I would take and use that. The thing is Im not sure when tranpose = inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpose is not the same as inverse for colour matrices, as they are not orthogonal (`M transpose times M = I`)

There are libraries for Processing that can invert matrices: 
http://adilapapaya.com/papayastatistics/

```
float[][] invA = Mat.inverse(A);
```

Alternatively there are a huge number of matrix libraries for Java, which you might be able to use, e.g. https://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/.

However, as you only need 3D matrix inversion, you could invert it manually using 9 lines of code, each with the appropriate formulae (see http://www.wikihow.com/Inverse-a-3X3-Matrix). This would probably be faster and use less memory than any of the pre-made solutions!

Comment: I looked up a youtube tutorial on how to find the matrix inverse. And i did the calculations for mine on paper. With that I could probably now do it with a few lines of code like you said. What you've given me is perfect for future use when I don't want to work out the matrix inverse manually. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**Hope below code developed may be useful to you**

```
package com.test.testprogramms;

/**
 * 
 * @author bhavikambani
 *
 */
public class Matrix {

    private int nrows;
    private int ncols;
    private double[][] data;

    public Matrix(double[][] dat) {
        this.data = dat;
        this.setNrows(dat.length);
        this.setNcols(dat[0].length);
    }

    public Matrix(int nrow, int ncol) {
        this.setNrows(nrow);
        this.setNcols(ncol);
        data = new double[nrow][ncol];
    }

    public int getNcols() {
        return ncols;
    }

    public void setNcols(int ncols) {
        this.ncols = ncols;
    }

    public int getNrows() {
        return nrows;
    }

    public void setNrows(int nrows) {
        this.nrows = nrows;
    }

    public double getValueAt(int i, int j) {
        return data[i][j];
    }

    public void setValueAt(int i, int j, double valueToBeSet){
        data[i][j] = valueToBeSet;
    }
}
```

**And below is utility class,**

```
package com.test.testprogramms;

/**
 * 
 * @author bhavikambani
 *
 */
public class MatrixUtil {

    public static Matrix transpose(Matrix matrix) {
        Matrix transposedMatrix = new Matrix(matrix.getNcols(), matrix.getNrows());
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.getNrows(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.getNcols(); j++) {
                transposedMatrix.setValueAt(j, i, matrix.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
        }
        return transposedMatrix;
    }
}
```